# A Timer Construct to Simplify Timing Blocks of Code

Tags: scala, timer

This is fairly simple, so I'm just looking for ideas on anything that can be cleaned up, places it can be extended, and suggestions regarding style/naming (I'm terrible at naming).

It allows you to write something like:

```
object TimerTest extends App {
        import Timers._

        val time: Long = TimeBlock { timer =>

                println("Starting...")
                println(timer.interTime)

                val s = (0 to 500000).foldRight(0)(_+_)
                println(timer.interTime)

                val s2 = (0 to 100000).foldRight(0)(_*_)
                println(timer.interTime)

                val s3 = (0 to 100000).foldRight(0)((x, y) => x + y * y + x)

        }

        println("Final Time: " + time)
}
```

Timer.scala:

```
object Timers {
    case class Timer(startTime: Long = new Date().getTime) {
        private def curMs: Long = new Date().getTime

        //Shortcut to start a new timer using a previous one
        def restart: Timer = Timer(curMs)

        //Doesn't actually stop it, because it's immutable
        //  Returns the amount of time since the Timer was started
        def stop: Long = curMs - startTime

        //To be used in a TimeBlock to get an intermediate time
        def interTime: Long = stop

        //Same as stop, but also returns a new Timer that starts where the
        // previous one ended
        def lap: (Long, Timer) = { val curTime = curMs
            (curTime - startTime, Timer(curTime))
        }
    }

    //Convenience class to help manage starting/stopping
    //  It supplies the internal timer to check intermediate times
    //    within the block
    case class TimeBlock(body: Timer => Unit) {
        val t = Timer()
        body(t)

        def stop = t.stop
    }

    //Same as the other TimeBlock, but simpler
    //  Doesn't supply the timer, so you can't check intermediate times
    class SimpleTimeBlock(body: => Unit) {
        val t = Timer()
        body

        def stop: Long = t.stop
    }
    object SimpleTimeBlock {
        def apply[A](body: => A) =
            new SimpleTimeBlock(body)
    }

    //Implicits to auto-stop TimeBlocks so they return the elapsed time
    implicit def StopLooseTimeBlocks(tB: TimeBlock): Long =
        tB.stop

    implicit def StopLooseSTimeBlocks(tB: SimpleTimeBlock): Long =
        tB.stop

}
```